# Android Studio Canary 2020.3.1: Apply Changes and Restart Activity (disabled: debug execution)

Tags: android, android-studio

In current version of Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1 Canary 12) I always have toolbar button `Apply Changes and Restart Activity` in *disabled* state.

[image]

- Mouseover hint says: *Apply Changes and Restart Activity (disabled: debug execution)*
- Hint in status bar says: *Apply changes and restart activity is disabled for this device because it is currently not allowed during debugging*

None of these messages help me in understanding of why "it is currently **not** allowed".
With this feature not available it is not possible to apply hot-updates to activity layouts.

Note: similar button "Apply Code Changes" works OK.

Any ideas how to enable "Apply Changes and Restart Activity"?

Comment: And you are doing this without the debugger being attached?

Comment: Of course topic is about application started from studio in debug mode, otherwise 'Apply Code Changes' would not work.

Comment: I'm not talking about debug mode. I'm talking about the debugger being attached. The error is saying that you are debugging, as in waiting for breakpoints.

Comment: When application is started in debug mode, debugger is attached automatically - so in this regard - yes, debugger is attached. 

I just tried starting running in non-debug mode - "Apply Changes and Restart Activity" became available (and  'Apply Code Changes' too). That's weird, really. Why I'm restricted when debugger is attached !? 

I remember it was working under debugger some long time ago, I'm back to android development after one year interval. May it depend on newer versions of Android OS in device/emulator or whatever else? That limitation is really annoying.

Comment: My guess would be that byte code swapping is impossible during debugging? Or perhaps they disabled it due to bugs, or perhaps try an Android 11 device? I have no idea as well. But why would you develop with the debugger constantly attached anyway? You can add it whenever you want if you actually need to debug code, you don't need to restart for that.